# CanCan Ability: can read Class if he can read at leas one Object of class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, cancancan

In cancan to be Able to :read all User for exemple we need

```
can :read,User
```

to be able to see a specific instance of the user we need

```
can :read, User do |user|
    user == something (condition satisfied ==> ability satisfied)
end
```

Now my question is :
is it possible to check if the user can read at least one instance??
i have a menu where i have to show "users" in the menu if he can at least read one instance of a user otherwise not showing anything

Comment: I guess nobody's answering because the answer depends on the exact condition you're using. If accessibility can be expressed as a scope, it's dead-simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
if User.accessible_by(current_ability,:read) > 0
```